# Set LC_MESSAGES locale for all users

Tags: gnome, locale

I have configured the `/etc/default/locale` file like:

```
LANG="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
LC_COLLATE=C
```

But when I enter in my gnome session the locales are:

```
LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=es_ES:en
LC_CTYPE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE=C
LC_MONETARY="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

`LC_COLLATE` is correct but `LC_MESSAGES` is set to `es_ES.UTF-8`.
In terminal console tty1 the locales are correct, so the problem is with Gnome but I don't know where to change this to be common to all users.

Answer (score 2):

The [Ubuntu Community Documentation on Locales](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale) states that:

> The gnome display manager (GDM) has its own settings, including
>   `GDM_LANG` for example, and is known to change locale settings when
>   running `/etc/gdm/Xsession`. You may want to examine GDM's cache
>   (`/var/cache/gdm/$USER/dmrc`) and restart GDM.

So please check that and correct it as required to resolve the issue.